# How to Draw a point on over a bitmap image drawn on a canvas by specifying the x and y co-ordinate in android?

Tags: android, canvas

I have drawn a bitmap image over a canvas.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sq);
        canvas.drawColor(color.black);  
        Rect dstRectForRender = new Rect(0,0,320,450);               
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, null,dstRectForRender,null);
```

The image gets displayed based on my screnn on a cnavs.
On my touch input, I need to pass the x and y co-ordinate position of the image and fill that pixel with a color to show that the image is painted on a drag event.
How can I pass the x and y coo-ordinate parameters? Which functions should I use to plot the pixels on the image?
I appreciate your help and sweet time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the *best* way to do this, but it would be much easier to do this if you defined your own subclass of `ImageView` and name it something like `DrawableImageView`. You'd have to make sure you implement all the basic constructors from `ImageView`, then override the `onTouchEvent` method. From that event you can get the touch coordinates and store them in an `ArrayList<Point>` and use that ArrayList by overriding the `onDraw` method and "painting" the image.

```
public class DrawableImageView extends ImageView {

ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();    

//constructors..

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    list.add(new Point(x,y));
    invalidate();
}
```

This is just a very brief overview of how to start your class, and may not be the most accurate way of doing things (depending on your specific code). Now, instead of using `<ImageView>` tags in your xml (or, loading an ImageView programatically), you refer to your subclass like so:

```
<your.package.name.DrawableImageView
/>
```

### Edit

In response to your comment, there is no predetermined way to draw over an image. You must implement this yourself, which is why I recommended storing `Points` in an ArrayList. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, but to draw (for example) black dots over an image you have to override `onDraw`:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    for(Point p : list) {

        //Draw black point at x and y.. I'm posting from my cell so I can't go into much detail
   }
}
```

Also, to force a View to redraw itself you need to use the `invalidate()` method in your `onTouchEvent()` (which I've added above).

Comment: Hey Snailer,
Thank you so much for your time and response.
Is there a method in drawable to plot on the image? Even if I used the Drawableimageview..How would I draw over the image. I ma new to andorid. Can you refer me some methods.. I tried hard finding the method with corresponding co-ordinate parameters but couldn't. Please help me on this. Sorry to bother you with more questions.

Comment: Snailer..Thank you so much,it's very helpful! I try working on this.